# I am making linux command Program by C-language. and I want to know what is wrong the code?

Tags: c, linux, exec, strdup

I wanna ask about how to make exec process programing by C.
Now, I typed like these code, and I use strtok and strdup.

my code wrong assign value from input, so could you see my code and could you teach what is wrong in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  int pid;
  int status, i = 0;
  char input[256], path[30];
  const char* a[10];
  char* token;
  char* split = " ";

  while(input != "exit"){
    printf("Please type your command:\n");
    fgets(input, 256, stdin); /* emxape: ls -alf    argv[0] = "ls" argv[1] = -alf*/
    printf("Input: %s", input);
    i = 0;
    token = strdup(strtok(input,split));

while(token != NULL){
  a[i] = token;
  token = strdup(strtok(NULL,split));
  printf("a%d is %s\n", i, a[i]);
  i++;
}

int j = 0;
while( j < sizeof(a))
  {
    printf("%s", a[j]);
    j++;
  }

//free(copy);



if(strcmp(a[0],"cd")== 0 )/*for compare pointer*/
{
  if (chdir((a[1])) == 0) {
    printf("Sucess change Directory.\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    printf("Fault change Directroy\n");
    perror("");
  }

  if (a[1] == NULL)
    {
      if(chdir(getenv("HOME"))<<0)
        perror("cd");
      return 0;
    }
  else
    {
      if(chdir(a[1]) <0)
        perror("cd");
    }



}

sprintf(path,"%s",a[0]);

pid = fork();

/*Child process*/
if(pid == 0){
   //execl(path,a[0],a[1],NULL);
   execl(a[0],a[1],a[2],NULL);
   printf("Wrong child process: %s",path);
   exit(0);
  }

  /*Parents Process*/
   else {
    wait(&status);
   }
  }//while
   printf("Thank you.");
 }/*main*/
```

Comment: General hint: `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);` avoids duplicating magic numbers, 256 in this case. It works only if read buffer is `char[]` instead of pointer, though.

Comment: From some specified input, what is the _expected_ output? And what is the _actual_ output? What happens when you run your program? Are there crashes? Have you tried stepping though the code in a debugger? Could you perhaps narrow the problem down to a few specific lines of code?

Comment: You should also remember that the extra arguments to `execl` is used to build the `argv` array for the other programs `main` function. This means that the first argument is the program name again, so you might want to try e.g. `execl(a[0], a[0], a[1], a[2], NULL);`

Comment: And please fix the indentation of your code, unless some kind soul edits your post for you first, it's kind of hard to follow when indentation is wrong.

Comment: Hint: compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and use the `gdb` debugger (so learn how to use it).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 problems

1. Line 26:  `token = strdup(strtok(NULL,split));`  should be `token = strdup(strtok(input,split));`
2. After the first modification, the loop in line 24 can run. but still does not run correctly. It seems the `strtok()`, and `strdup()` does not run correctly.